# Closed formula for the general term of a sequence (using factorials)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the sequences $a_{n+2}=\frac{2a_{n}}{n+2}$ I am trying to find a general way of expressing this in terms of $a_{k}$ I keep getting $a_{k}=\frac{a_{0}}{\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)!}$ but I am told it is $a_{k}=\frac{a_{0}}{k!}$. I got my answer through general inspection of a few values of n.

Comment: I believe you are right.

Comment: The last formula is relative to recurrence : $a_{n+1}=a_n/n$. Besides, it is strange that your sequence is only defined for even indices $a_{2k}$. What do you do with the odd ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessarily the values of $ a_0 $ and $ a_1 $ have to be given previously. Assume that the values of $ a_0 $ and $ a_1$ are known. 
$$
\begin{matrix}
n=0 \implies& a_{0+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_0}{0+2} \implies& a_{2}=\frac{1}{1}a_0
\\
n=2 \implies& a_{2+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_2}{2+2} \implies& a_{4}=\frac{1}{2}a_2=\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}a_0
\\
n=4 \implies& a_{4+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_4}{4+2} \implies& a_{6}=\frac{1\cdot a_4}{3}=\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}a_0
\\
n=6 \implies& a_{6+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_6}{6+2} \implies& a_{8}=\frac{a_6}{4}
=\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4}a_0
\end{matrix}
$$

Assume induction that $ a_{2k} = \frac{1}{k!} a_0 $. Assume the result is valid for some $ k \geq 1 $. Then, as is proved below, the result is valid for $k+1$, that is, $ a_{2(k + 1)} = \frac{1}{(k + 1)!} a_0 $. In fact, 
$$
a_{2(k+2)}=a_{2k+2}=\frac{2}{2k+2}a_{2k}=\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{k!} a_0= \frac{1}{(k + 1)!} a_0
$$

On the other hand, we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
n=1 \implies& a_{1+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_1}{1+2} \implies& a_{3}=\frac{2}{3}a_1
\\
n=3 \implies& a_{3+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_3}{3+2} \implies& a_{5}=\frac{2}{5}a_3=\frac{2^2}{3\cdot 5}a_1
\\
n=5 \implies& a_{5+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_5}{5+2} \implies& a_{7}=\frac{2\cdot a_5}{7}=\frac{2^3}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}a_1
\\
n=7 \implies& a_{7+2}= \frac{2\cdot a_7}{7+2} \implies& a_{9}=\frac{a_7}{9}
=\frac{2^4}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9}a_1
\end{matrix}
$$

Assume, for all $k\geq 0$, induction that 
$$
a_{2k+1} = \frac{2}{2k+1}a_{2(k-1)-1}=\frac{2^k}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)} a_1. 
$$ 
Assume the result is valid for some $ k \geq 0 $. Then, as is proved below, the result is valid for $k+1$, that is, $ a_{2(k + 1)+1} = \frac{1}{(k + 1)!} a_1$. In fact, 
\begin{align}
a_{2(k+1)+1}=&a_{(2k+1)+2}
\\
=&\frac{2}{(2k+1)+2}a_{2k+1}
\\
=&\frac{2}{(2k+1)+2}\frac{2^k}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)} a_1
\\
=&\frac{2}{2(k+1)+1}\frac{2^k}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)} a_1
\\
=&\frac{2^{(k+1)}}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)\cdot [2(k+1)+1]} a_1
\end{align}
Now, note that 
$$
a_{2k}=\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots \cdot k}a_0=\frac{2^k}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k)}a_0
$$
This leads us to the following conclusion.
$$
a_{n}
=\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{2^k}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k)}a_0
& \quad 
& \mbox{ if } n=2k
\\
\\
\frac{2^k}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot \ldots \cdot (2k+1)}a_1
& \quad 
& \mbox{ if } n=2k+1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Your final answer can take advantage of "double factorial" symbol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial